# How to address "opaque type `impl Future<Output = Self>` does not satisfy its associated type bounds" warning when using async in trait?

Tags: rust, async-await, traits

I get a warning from the following code:

```rust
trait AsyncClient {
    async fn new(host: &str, port: u16) -> Self;
}
```

```
warning: opaque type `impl Future<Output = Self>` does not satisfy its associated type bounds
  --> src/lib.rs:2:5
   |
2  |     async fn new(host: &str, port: u16) -> Self;
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
  ::: /playground/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/core/src/future/future.rs:40:5
   |
40 |     type Output;
   |     ------------ this associated type bound is unsatisfied for `Self`
   |
   = note: `#[warn(opaque_hidden_inferred_bound)]` on by default
```

How to fix the warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So. This is a weird one.

First of all, this is considered a bug and already fixed in nightly since [#120360](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/120360).

Now to the explanation.

The code in the question desugars to:

```rust
trait AsyncClient {
    fn new(host: &str, port: u16) -> impl std::future::Future<Output = Self>;
}
```

Note that `Self`, like in any trait, could be unsized (`?Sized`). However, a critical observation is that the associated type [`std::future::Future::Output`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/future/trait.Future.html#associatedtype.Output) does not have a `?Sized` bound, and therefore implicitly requires `Sized`. So we have a mismatch: `Future::Output` requires `Sized`, but `Self` could be `?Sized`.

Such code was accepted by the compiler in the past but is intended to be phased out, and this is the intent of [`opaque_hidden_inferred_bound`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/rustc/lints/listing/warn-by-default.html#opaque-hidden-inferred-bound): to lint against such cases.

In this case specifically, however, the code should be accepted, similar to what we allow methods to return `Self` even though `Self` might be unsized. Which is why a fix was introduced.

Answer (score 4):

Adding `: Sized` bound fixed the problem.

Either on the whole trait:

```rust
trait AsyncClient: Sized {
    async fn new(host: &str, port: u16) -> Self;
}
```

Or just on the method:

```
trait AsyncClient {
    async fn new(host: &str, port: u16) -> Self where Self: Sized;
}
```